# Display a column based on condition in Angular

Tags: angular

I am developing an Angular 4 application and want to display a column only if `totalYears <= 7`. I have a `ngFor` and `ngIf` in the `th` element. I am currently getting an error. How do I handle it?

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <!-- <ng-container *ngIf="yearList.length > 6">  -->
      <th *ngIf="totalYears <=7" *ngFor="let year of yearList"> {{year}}</th>
      <!-- </ng-container> -->
      <th>Remaining Years</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: can you add the complete code

Comment: And what is the error message exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular doesn't support more than one structural directive on the same element.

You have an `ngFor` and an `ngIf` too on your `th` element:

```
<th *ngIf="totalYears<=7" *ngFor="let year of yearList">{{year}}</th>
```

You can do something like this instead:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="totalYears<=7">
    <th *ngFor="let year of yearList">{{year}}</th>                                
</ng-container>
```

Source: https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#one-per-element

Also: `totalYears` should be accessible in this template view. Try printing `totalYears` like {{totalYears}} for debugging, for example.